# Optaplanner - see if the same item appears in two lists

Tags: java, optaplanner, timetable

I am currently trying to make an exam timetabling program. I have got it so that the exams are assigned to a timeslot however the student conflict part is not working.
I currently have my students in lists as attributes of subject objects. Each exam also has a subject attribute which is an instance of a subject class. The problem I'm having is that when comparing the lists of students it is being said that there are no conflicts as the list are not identical. However I need it to search through the lists and see if there is the same string appears in both.
I'm very new to this so if anyone could sagest a better way of structuring my problem or a solve for the looking in the strings I would be very grateful.

```
private Constraint studentConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
        // students can only sit one exam at the same time
        // selects a lesson and pairs it with another one
        return constraintFactory
                .forEach(Exam.class)
                .join(Exam.class,
                        //...in the same timeslot ...
                        Joiners.equal(Exam::getTimeslot),
                        //...has the same students ...
                        Joiners.equal(Exam::getStudentstoString))
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("Student conflict");
    }
```

section of output:

[section of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8OcR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a filter.

```
private Constraint studentConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
    // students can only sit one exam at the same time
    // selects a lesson and pairs it with another one
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Exam.class)
            .join(Exam.class,
                    Joiners.equal(Exam::getTimeslot))
            .filter((exam1, exam2) -> {
                 // call any code that compares the two lists and returns true on overlap
            })
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("Student conflict");
}
```

This is the best you can do with the current model. However, it is probably not very efficient. Every time an `Exam` is evaluated, the filter is executed and the lists will be compared in their entirety.

We can do better. Assuming that a `Student` is a problem fact or a planning entity, you can do this, which will be much more incremental:

```
private Constraint studentConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
    // students can only sit one exam at the same time
    // selects a lesson and pairs it with another one
    return constraintFactory.forEachUniquePair(Exam.class,
            Joiners.equal(Exam::getTimeslot))
        .ifExists(Student.class,
            Joiners.filtering((exam1, exam2, student) -> 
                exam1.getStudents().contains(student) &&
                exam2.getStudents().contains(student))
        .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
        .asConstraint("Student conflict");
}
```

Needless to say, for this to be as efficient as possible, `getStudents()` should return a `Set`, not a `List`. (Or the lists should be very small.)