# How is it possible to spread exams of students in optaplanner?

Tags: java, constraints, optaplanner

I am learning to work with optaplanner. I need to spread exams of one student. The less time between two exams of one student, the more penalty I give.

I need the Integer List ExamIds of my Student class because there are all the exams for that one student.

Then I need to check all these Exams planned Timeslots with eachother to give them more time between.

What i tried is following code:

`

```
Constraint spaceBetweenExams(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Student.class)
            .join(Exam.class)
            .join(Exam.class)
            .filter((student, exam1, exam2) ->{
                if(student.getExamIds().contains(exam1.getID()) && student.getExamIds().contains(exam2.getID())){
                    if(exam1.getID() < exam2.getID()){
                        int timeDifference = Math.abs(exam1.getTimeslot().getID() - exam2.getTimeslot().getID());
                        if (timeDifference == 1) {
                            penalty = 16;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 2) {
                            penalty = 8;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 3) {
                            penalty = 4;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 4) {
                            penalty = 2;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 5) {
                            penalty = 1;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            })
            .penalize("Max time between exams", HardSoftScore.ofSoft(penalty));
```

`

The result I get is 24645 soft penalties but optaplanner doesn't even try to fix them.
I think that the way I check the exams in the code above is not fully correct.

This is my constraint class :

```
public class ExamTableConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    int penalty = 0;
    List<Integer> studentExamIds;

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[]{
                // Hard constraints
                twoExamForStudentConflict(constraintFactory),
                // Soft constraints
                spaceBetweenExams(constraintFactory)
            };
    }

    private Constraint twoExamForStudentConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Exam.class)
                .join(Exam.class,
                        Joiners.equal(Exam::getTimeslot),
                        Joiners.lessThan(Exam::getID))
                .filter((exam1, exam2) -> {
                    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(exam1.getSID());
                    result.retainAll(exam2.getSID());
                    return result.size() > 0;
                })
                .penalize("Student conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }

    Constraint spaceBetweenExams(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Student.class)
                .join(Exam.class)
                .join(Exam.class)
                .filter((student, exam1, exam2) ->{
                    if(student.getExamIds().contains(exam1.getID()) && student.getExamIds().contains(exam2.getID())){
                        if(exam1.getID() < exam2.getID()){
                            int timeDifference = Math.abs(exam1.getTimeslot().getID() - exam2.getTimeslot().getID());
                            if (timeDifference == 1) {
                                penalty = 16;
                            } else if (timeDifference == 2) {
                                penalty = 8;
                            } else if (timeDifference == 3) {
                                penalty = 4;
                            } else if (timeDifference == 4) {
                                penalty = 2;
                            } else if (timeDifference == 5) {
                                penalty = 1;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .penalize("Max time between exams", HardSoftScore.ofSoft(penalty));

    }

    /*Constraint spaceBetweenExams(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        penalty = 0;
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Student.class)
                .join(Exam.class,
                        equal(Student::getExamIds, Exam::getID),
                        filtering((student, exam1) -> exam1.getTimeslot() != null))
                .join(Exam.class,
                        equal((student, exam1) -> student.getExamIds(), Exam::getID),
                        equal((student, exam1) -> exam1.getTimeslot(), Exam::getTimeslot),
                        filtering((student, exam1, exam2) -> {
                        int timeDifference = getPeriodBetweenExams(exam1, exam2);
                        if (timeDifference == 1) {
                            penalty += 16;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 2) {
                            penalty += 8;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 3) {
                            penalty += 4;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 4) {
                            penalty += 2;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 5) {
                            penalty += 1;
                        }
                    if(penalty == 0){
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }))
                .penalize("Max time between exams", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);

    }*/


}
```

And this is the class where I start the program:

```
 public class ExamTableApp {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExamTableApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SolverFactory<ExamTable> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
                .withSolutionClass(ExamTable.class)
                .withEntityClasses(Exam.class)
                .withConstraintProviderClass(ExamTableConstraintProvider.class)
                // The solver runs only for 5 seconds on this small dataset.
                // It's recommended to run for at least 5 minutes ("5m") otherwise.
                .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(30)));

        // Load the problem
        ExamTable problem = getData();

        // Solve the problem
        Solver<ExamTable> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
        ExamTable solution = solver.solve(problem);

        // Visualize the solution
        printTimetable(solution);
    }

    public static ExamTable getData(){
        DataReader parser = new DataReader("benchmarks/sta-f-83.crs", "benchmarks/sta-f-83.stu");

        List<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<>(1);
        roomList.add(new Room(1,"Room A"));
//        roomList.add(new Room(2,"Room B"));
//        roomList.add(new Room(3,"Room C"));

        List<Exam> examList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<Integer, Exam> exams = parser.getExams();
        Set<Integer> keys = exams.keySet();
        for (Integer i : keys) {
            Exam exam = exams.get(i);
            examList.add(new Exam(exam.getID(),  exam.getSID()));
        }

        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<Integer, Student> students = parser.getStudents();
        Set<Integer> keys2 = students.keySet();
        for (Integer i : keys2) {
            Student student = students.get(i);
            studentList.add(new Student(student.getID(), student.getExamIds()));
        }

        return new ExamTable(parser.getTimeslots(), roomList, examList, studentList);
    }

    private static void printTimetable(ExamTable examTable) {
        LOGGER.info("");
        List<Room> roomList = examTable.getRoomList();
        List<Exam> examList = examTable.getExamList();
        Map<TimeSlot, Map<Room, List<Exam>>> examMap = examList.stream()
                .filter(exam -> exam.getTimeslot() != null && exam.getRoom() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Exam::getTimeslot, Collectors.groupingBy(Exam::getRoom)));
        LOGGER.info("|            | " + roomList.stream()
                .map(room -> String.format("%-10s", room.getName())).collect(Collectors.joining(" | ")) + " |");
        LOGGER.info("|" + "------------|".repeat(roomList.size() + 1));
        for (TimeSlot timeslot : examTable.getTimeslotList()) {
            List<List<Exam>> cellList = roomList.stream()
                    .map(room -> {
                        Map<Room, List<Exam>> byRoomMap = examMap.get(timeslot);
                        if (byRoomMap == null) {
                            return Collections.<Exam>emptyList();
                        }
                        List<Exam> cellLessonList = byRoomMap.get(room);
                        if (cellLessonList == null) {
                            return Collections.<Exam>emptyList();
                        }
                        return cellLessonList;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            LOGGER.info("| " + String.format("%-10s",
                    timeslot.getID() + " " + " | "
                    + cellList.stream().map(cellLessonList -> String.format("%-10s",
                    cellLessonList.stream().map(Exam::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" | "))
                    + " |"));

            LOGGER.info("|" + "------------|".repeat(roomList.size() + 1));
        }
        List<Exam> unassignedExams = examList.stream()
                .filter(exam -> exam.getTimeslot() == null || exam.getRoom() == null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (!unassignedExams.isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.info("");
            LOGGER.info("Unassigned lessons");
            for (Exam exam : unassignedExams) {
                LOGGER.info("  " + exam.getName() + " - " + exam.getNumberOfStudents() + " - " + exam.getSID());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a suspicion that you have not actually tried to run this constraint. This constraint does not even compile. (See the `penalty` variable in the `ofSoft(...)` call. That variable does not exist in this scope.) Please include the code that you actually attempted to run. (Well, in theory, the `penalty` variable may be statically imported from somewhere, but if that is the case, that is a major part of your issues and we need to know.)

Comment: @LukášPetrovický I added the full code files do you have enough information with this?

Comment: @LukášPetrovický exactly the 24645 soft penalty is when I set .ONE_SOFT in place of my custom penalty. Then I get 0 soft penalty but the solution isn’t correct either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided shows one major misunderstanding of how Constraint Streams work, which in turn makes it fundamentally broken.

Any instance of `ConstraintProvider` *must be stateless*. Even though you technically can have fields in that class, there is no use for it, as the constraints - when run - need to be without side effects. This way, you have introduced [score corruptions](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#environmentMode) and probably have not even noticed.

Also, the constraint weight `HardScore.ofSoft(...)` is only computed once during constraint creation, not at solver runtime, therefore defining it like you did would have been pointless anyway. (Its value will be whatever `penalty` was at instantiation, therefore `0`.) What you need to use instead is a match weight, which is computed at runtime. Making just that modification, the constraint in question would look like this:

```
Constraint spaceBetweenExams(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Student.class)
            .join(Exam.class)
            .join(Exam.class)
            .filter((student, exam1, exam2) -> {
                if(student.getExamIds().contains(exam1.getID()) && student.getExamIds().contains(exam2.getID())){
                    if(exam1.getID() < exam2.getID()){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            })
            .penalize("Max time between exams", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
                (student, exam1, exam2) ->{
                        int timeDifference = Math.abs(exam1.getTimeslot().getID() - exam2.getTimeslot().getID());
                        if (timeDifference == 1) {
                            return 16;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 2) {
                            return 8;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 3) {
                            return 4;
                        } else if (timeDifference == 4) {
                            return 2;
                        } else {
                            return 1;
                        }
                }
            });
}
```

The above code will at least make this code run properly, but it will likely be slow. See [my other recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833213/optaplanner-see-if-the-same-item-appears-in-two-lists) for inspiration on how to change your domain model to improve performance of your constraints. It may not fit exactly, but the idea seems valid to your use case as well.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are explaining. Now the program has runned for 5 minutes but the soft penalty is extremely high. It is 1hard penalty and 110852 soft penalty. 

Can I conclude I need more time for the correct solution because it is likely slow or do I have another problem in the way I check the constraint?

Comment: This constraint will create a lot of matches - each student with every pair of exams, other than those filtered out. Each of those constraint matches will be penalized by your function. The total soft penalty will be large. I'd be more worried that you're still seeing hard constraints broken - after 5 minutes, for small problems, I wouldn't expect that anymore. Your hard constraint has a score trap - use a match weight to penalize by the actual number of results; that may help. You should also be aware that the constraints are written very slow, but that is not in scope of this question.

Comment: Yes, it is very slow written but that is changeable. After 30 minutes I still have 1 hard penalty. The weird thing here is before the soft constraint was impelemented I had 0 hard penalty.